# Component YiiBooster datepickerRow error : Property.* is not defined

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, datepicker

I always got an error: Property "TbDatePicker.hint" is not defined. and when I comment it, it also got an error: Property "TbDatePicker.prepend" is not defined.

My code:

```
echo $form->datepickerRow($formModel,'date',
        array(
            'options' => array('language' => 'es'),
            'hint' => 'Click inside! This is a super cool date field.',
            'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same error today.
The function definition of datePickerRow (see TbActiveForm.php) is:

```
public function datePickerRow($model, $attribute, $widgetOptions = array(), $rowOptions = array())
```

According to TbActiveForm class information (in the beginning of the corresponding file), it says that both hint and prepend are rowOptions, so to make your datePicker function you have to rewrite your code as follows:

```
echo $form->datepickerRow(
        $formModel,
        'date',
        array('options' => array('language' => 'es'),),
        array(
            'hint' => 'Click inside! This is a super cool date field.',
            'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
        )
);
```

The only thing I couldn't deal with, is that the prepended icon gets slightly above the input field.

Comment: Got it, in the form.css file in the css folder at the root of the web application, you have to comment lines 41-46, whether it sets div.form.input, div.form textarea, div.form select { margin: 0.2em 0 0.5em 0;}

Comment: I have been looking in TbActiveForm.php and I did not realize it was it. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Yes unequal number of parameters passed from view page to the datepickerRow function. :)